# Leveraging user context in an IHostedService via DI

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ihostedservice

I have a series of class libraries that are used in `asp.net-core` middleware, and in an `IHostedService`.

To fetch the user context, I can inject `IHttpContextAccessor` to grab the `HttpContext` user:

```cs
public class MyLibrary 
{
  public MyLibrary(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
  {
    // set the accessor - no problem
  }
  
  public async Task DoWorkAsync(SomeObject payload) 
  { 
    // get the user from the accessor
    // do some work
  }
}
```

To be a little more abstract, I have an `IUserAccessor` with an `HttpUserAccessor` implementation:

```cs
public class HttpUserAccessor: IUserAccessor
{
  IHttpContextAccessor _httpaccessor;
  public HttpUserAccessor(IHttpContextAccessor accessor) 
  {
    _httpaccessor = accessor;
  }

  public string GetUser()
  {
    // return user from _httpaccessor
  }
}
```

and then `MyLibrary` does not need an `IHttpContextAccessor` dependency:

```cs
public class MyLibrary 
{
  public MyLibrary(IUserAccessor accessor)
  {
    // set the accessor - no problem
  }
  
  public async Task DoWorkAsync(SomeObject payload) 
  { 
    // get the user from the accessor
    // do some work
  }
}
```

My `IHostedService` is popping message from a queue, where the message includes:

- a user context, and
- a serialized `SomeObject` to pass to `MyLibrary.DoWorkAsync`

So, something like:

```cs
public class MyHostedService : IHostedService
{
  IServiceScopeProvider _serviceScopeFactory;

  public MyHostedService(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory) 
  {
    _serviceScopeFactory = servicesScopeFactory;
  }

  public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  { ... }

  public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  { ... }

  public async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
  {
    foreach (var message in queue) 
    {
      using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope()) 
      {
        // todo: tell IUserAccessor what message.User is!
        var payload = // create a SomeObject from the queue message
        var mylibrary = _services.GetRequiredService<MyLibrary>();
        await myLibrary.DoWorkAsync(payload);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, my question is, how does `MyHostedService` store `message.User` **in such a way that a custom `IUserAccessor` can access it** in a thread-safe manner via DI?

Comment: Injecting `IServiceProvider` is a code smell. [And for good reason](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AspNetCoreGuidance.md#do-not-capture-services-injected-into-the-controllers-on-background-threads). You should be using `IServiceScopeFactory`, but keep in mind that the work you are doing is outside the request pipeline. Results may vary or not work at all. You shouldn't depend on scoped services inside of something that is similar to Singleton, which `IHostedService` is.

Comment: [Here](https://www.blog.jamesmichaelhickey.com/NET-Core-Dependency-Injection/) is some more reading.

Comment: @Andy, good point. I've updated the sample `IHostedService` in the question.

Your point about managing scoped services inside `IHostedService` is exactly my question: what's the "right" way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how does MyHostedService store message.User in such a way that a custom IUserAccessor can access it in a thread-safe manner via DI?

The thing you're looking for is `AsyncLocal<T>` - it's like a thread-local variable but scoped to a (possibly asynchronous) code block instead of a thread.

I tend to prefer a "provider" + "accessor" pairing for this: one type that provides the value, and a separate type that reads the value. This is logically the same thing as a React Context in the JS world, though the implementation is quite different.

One tricky thing about `AsyncLocal<T>` is that you need to *overwrite* its value on any change. In this case, that's not really a problem (no message processing will want to update the "user"), but in the general case it's important to keep in mind. I prefer storing immutable types in the `AsyncLocal<T>` to ensure they aren't mutated directly instead of overwriting the value. In this case, your "user" is a `string`, which is already immutable, so that's perfect.

First, you'll need to define the actual `AsyncLocal<T>` to hold the user value and define some low-level accessors. I strongly recommend using `IDisposable` to ensure the `AsyncLocal<T>` value is unset properly at the end of the scope:

```
public static class AsyncLocalUser
{
  private static AsyncLocal<string> _local = new AsyncLocal<string>();
  private static IDisposable Set(string newValue)
  {
    var oldValue = _local.Value;
    _local.Value = newValue;

    // I use Nito.Disposables; feel free to replace with another IDisposable implementation.
    return Disposable.Create(() => _local.Value = oldValue);
  }
  private static string Get() => _local.Value;
}
```

Then you can define a provider:

```
public static class AsyncLocalUser
{
  ... // see above
  public sealed class Provider
  {
    public IDisposable SetUser(string value) => Set(value);
  }
}
```

and the accessor is similarly simple:

```
public static class AsyncLocalUser
{
  ... // see above
  public sealed class Accessor : IUserAccessor
  {
    public string GetUser() => Get();
  }
}
```

You'll want to set up your DI to point `IUserAccessor` to `AsyncLocalUser.Accessor`. You can also optionally add `AsyncLocalUser.Provider` to your DI, or you can just create it directly.

Usage would go something like this:

```
foreach (var message in queue) 
{
  using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope()) 
  {
    var userProvider = new AsyncLocalUser.Provider(); // (or get it from DI)
    using (userProvider.SetUser(message.User))
    {
      var payload = // create a SomeObject from the queue message
      var mylibrary = _services.GetRequiredService<MyLibrary>();
      await myLibrary.DoWorkAsync(payload);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I saw the use of `AsyncLocal` in `IHttpContextAccessor`, but the use of `Set` was unclear to me.  This clarifies it - I'll give this a shot shortly!